# Mac OS Terminal: Can't get composer on the global environment

Tags: php, macos, bash, composer-php

So I have been trying to setup my MAMP and Laravel but stuck at getting the composer to work.

I have installed MAMP, and I use the command:

`curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`

and I tried running

`php composer.phar`

everything works so far.

Then when I tried to put composer into my global path (I assume the following line does it)

`mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer`

I receive this error

`mv: rename composer.phar to /usr/local/bin/composer: No such file or directory`

I tried `mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin` as well it gives the same error.

Here is my `echo $PATH`:
`/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin`

Any pointers on resolving this? Oh, Mac Rookie here.

Comment: Are you sure the `/usr/local/bin` directory exists?

Comment: Hmm.. good point. The $PATH by default included that directory, so I assumed it's there. How do I check this?

Comment: Brilliant, my own mistake. @scompt.com is right, I just assumed the folder is there because it is in my $PATH. All good now.

Comment: Added as an answer so I can get some rep love. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that `/usr/local/bin` exists. That's the error that you get when the target directory doesn't exist.

Comment: On some versions of OSX the /usr directory does not exist by default. If you receive the error "/usr/local/bin/composer: No such file or directory" then you must create the directory manually before proceeding: `sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin`