# Can't move composer

Tags: php, macos, composer-php

When I install composer on my mac with:

> curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

And then try to move it like this:

> sudo mv php composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

it's telling me:

> rename composer.phar to /usr/local/bin/composer: No such file or directory

When I look to my path:

> echo $PATH

It's telling me:

> /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mac OS Terminal: Can't get composer on the global environment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21643507/mac-os-terminal-cant-get-composer-on-the-global-environment)

Comment: Oke it's telling me that I;ve to make this directory but how can I do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try with below command to install composer globally.

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

Note: On some versions of OSX the /usr directory does not exist by default. If you receive the error "/usr/local/bin/composer: No such file or directory" then you must create the directory manually before proceeding: `sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin.`

Comment: thanks for your reply when I try: mkdir -p /usr/local/bin it's telling me "mkdir: /usr/local/bin: Permission denied"

Comment: try with sudo, `sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin`

Comment: @JamesWallen-Jones ~Thats it - also mv needs sudo as well

Answer (score 13):

If you are running macOS Sierra Version, there might not be a /usr/local/bin folder so you will have to create it. Follow these steps in the terminal:

```
Step 1: cd ~

Step 2: sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin

Step 3: curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when installing composer to make it global

1. create the directory is the error *no such file or directory* by using

> sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin

2. now install the composer direct to the bin folder

> sudo curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

3. run `composer` on the terminal and it should be working