# How do I move Composer?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I've seen some things similar ( [Can't move composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33868004/cant-move-composer) ) to this but I have yet to figure it out how to fix this problem.

I'm installing composer on linux(fedora 22) following this guide: https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/53409/does-fedora-has-composer-in-the-repo/?answer=53445#post-id-53445

The end result I am seeking is using laravel with docker for a group project but so far I'm stuck here with this error with composer.

I enter:  sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer in the command line and it kicks back this message: mv: cannot stat ‘composer.phar’: No such file or directory

I'm uncertain of whats happening here, is this expecting that there is already a composer file in /usr/local/bin/ , because there is not. It's obviously not creating one either.

Perhaps this is completely over my head, that said can someone explain what is going on here to me and help me reach a solution for installing composer?

Answer (score 2):

Download the [composer.phar](https://getcomposer.org/download/1.1.0-RC/composer.phar) manualy.

`cd` to the directory where you have the downloaded `composer.phar` and run the below command:

```
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer.phar
```

to move the `composer.phar` to the bin directory `/usr/local/bin`. Now restart the terminal and it should work. Note that it is a composer executable for Linux (didn't test it but it is in the [docs](https://getcomposer.org/installer)).

Comment: I have composer.phar in my /home however when I try to drag and drop it I get.  Error opening file '/usr/local/bin/composer.phar': Permission denied  and you saw what happens when I use the suggest 'mv' command in terminal.

Comment: type 'sudo su' in terminal then try to move it (i assume you are doing the moving with the terminal) or change the folder permission

Comment: or do this 'sudo nautilus --browser /usr/local/bin/' , the folder will open and paste composer.phar there

Comment: I get the permission garbage dragging and dropping, when I try moving it in terminal its like it doesn't exist, maybe I'm writing it incorrectly?

Comment: yea try to drag and drop, i dont realy know it should work!

Comment: cd to the directory where you have the downloaded composer.phar execute this 'sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer.phar' (if this didnt work use composer installer, link in the answer)

Comment: mv: cannot stat ‘composer.phar’: No such file or directory        this is getting ridiculous and its driving me to switch to unbuntu

Comment: a screenshot would be helpfull + try the installer

Comment: cd to the folder where you downloaded the composer.phar first('cd /home/user/Downloads') or something like that , then do the mv (the error here is that he can't find the composer.phar to move it in first place)

Comment: yeah thats what I said and yet its still kicking back this same thing                                                                                             [root@LE Downloads]# sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
mv: cannot stat ‘composer.phar’: No such file or directory
[root@LE Downloads]# sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer.phar
mv: cannot stat ‘composer.phar’: No such file or directory

Comment: Did you even download that file? You didn't show the output from the first command.

Answer (score 1):

I would adjust the move command above slightly to:

```
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

As per the instructions at https://getcomposer.org/download/

That way, you can actually run composer with just,

```
php composer
```

As it's located in your `/user/local/bin` as just `composer`. If you move it as `composer.phar` things get strange.

Note, moving the composer.phar won't relocate the composer.json and composer.lock files that will be the original directory where composer was installed, but the composer command will run fine.

Comment: That's not how it works. PHP can't just find things magically because they're in `/usr/local/bin`.